# Create an Android Virtual Device From a Java application Programmatically

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to create my Android virtual device from another java application.
I don't want to use the default Android AvdManager because you can't set where you want to create your AVD and it has problem with exotic caraters.

So I get the sdklib.jar of the AvdMagager and try to do this.

But I can't create a AVD because I have the log : 
Error
Unable to find a '%1$s' file for ABI %2$s to copy into the AVD folder.

This is an exemple of what I do :

```
class Choice implements ISdkLog {

    public Choice() {
    com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager avdmanager;
    try {
        com.android.sdklib.SdkManager manager = com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager("Boulet", this);
        IAndroidTarget[] targets = manager.getTargets();

        avdmanager= new com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager(manager,this);

        avdmanager.createAvd(new java.io.File("filename"), "dunno", targets[0], "dunno", "dunno", "dunno", null, false, false, false, this);

    } catch (AndroidLocationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
//Method of interface ISdkLog
@Override
public void error(Throwable arg0, String arg1, Object... arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Error");
    System.out.println(arg1);
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

@Override
public void printf(String arg0, Object... arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Log");
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

@Override
public void warning(String arg0, Object... arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Warning");
    System.out.println(arg0);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess a simple command line call is to simple, right? Because you can create a new avd from command line :)

Comment: Agreed, please use the documented command-line interface.

Comment: The problem with the command line in the new versions of Android tools it's that it waits for a user input (even with the --force parameter). So the Runtime.getRuntime().exec command is stuck.

Comment: I forget to precise that i wanted to create it from a Java application for my convenience like Google did with the AVDManager. The AVDManager is great but you can't set custom path with it. And command line can be annoying when you want to create AVD with params and options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to the system image the plateform must use.
I could create my avd on windows with this.

```
AvdManager avdmanager;
try {
    SdkManager manager = SdkManager.createManager("path/to/android/sdk/folder", this);
    IAndroidTarget[] targets = manager.getTargets();

    avdmanager= new AvdManager(manager,this);

    avdmanager.createAvd(new File("custom/path/for/your/avd","advname"), "advname", targets[0], target[0].getSystemImages()[0].getAbiType(), null, null, null,
            false, false, false, this);

} catch (AndroidLocationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The null parameters are options for skin, sdcard path, emulator params (screen params,etc...).

Comment: SdkManager included in which library ?

Comment: It's quite old so this piece of code may not be up to date anymore. The class is in sdk\tools\lib\sdklib.jar