# Create and Run Android Virtual Device

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have to create an android virtual device and run from my project done in java, for that I am using sdklib.jar, code that I have tried to do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603301/create-an-android-virtual-device-from-a-java-application-programmatically/9763758?noredirect=1#comment34698502_9763758) but it cannot create any virtual device, and I cannot create AvdManager object as in the link, it shows an error AvdManager has protected access in AvdManager, so how can I break this, please mention any other methods if you know.

I need to run it programatically

Comment: The simplest method is nothing but to use ADT rather than creating programmatically it will give you emulator directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Download latest [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk#download) and give it a try...maybe this can solve the bug you are suffering. 
open eclipse after extracting
1.go to Window
2.Click on Android Virtual Device
3.Create New.
Hope i am giving you correct solution.

Comment: hello, I have to create avd and run from inside my source code

Comment: I am not getting what u mean by "run from inside source code". Can u elaborate?

Comment: I have to run avd programaticaly

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you :
**Download [Updated ADT](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk#download) .**

After download open ADT close first window and follow the steps =

Go on **Window** -> **Android Virtual Device Manager** -> **New** -> **Give any Name** Suppose **First AVD** -> Select Device : suppose **3.7"FWVGA slider (480*854 : hdpi)** -> Give **SDcard Size** suppose **500** MB -> **OK**

Now **select First AVD** -> **click Start** (last option to right hand side) -> **Launch**

And its DONE your First AVD will get open. :)